# Delete a specific 3D threeJS Object in Autodesk Forge

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk, forge

I have a problem with the viewer.overlays.removeMesh. I can't delete a specific object from multiple 3D objects that I added using ThreeJS. For example, I created a function that creates multiple spheres and I can only delete the last object added, but I can't do that for the first object added. Any Help please.

You'll find my function below:

```
   _updateCurrentSphere(points) {
        const vertices = [];
        // Delete the first sphere after adding the 3rd one
        if (this.currentSphere[2]) {
            this.viewer.overlays.removeMesh(this.currentSphere[0], DrawWalkingPathLinesOverlayName);
            
        }
        
            this.currentSphere[indice] = this._createSpherePoint();
                    
            // Points used as pointer to position my spheres
            vertices.push(points[0].x, points[0].y, points[0].z);
            for (let i = 1, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
                vertices.push(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].z);
            }

            //Condition used later in my app
            if (indiceClickSph == 1){
                
            //Set the position of the sphere        
            } else {
                for (let i = 0, len = vertices.length; i < len; i=i+3) {
                    this.currentSphere[indice].position.set(vertices[i], vertices[i+1], vertices[i+2]);               
                    
                }
            }
            
            //Create sphere
            this.viewer.overlays.addMesh(this.currentSphere[indice], DrawWalkingPathLinesOverlayName);
            
         return    this.currentSphere[indice];
    }
```

Comment: create an array that holds all added Mesh. and u can use the array.shift() methods. then pass the return value to your removeMesh().

Comment: Rodener, I did that and it doesn't work.